# Simple AngularJS DOM update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a list of items, and when user clicks on one of them, I want that menu item's detail (item's class or the item's text itself -- i.e. the `$market` variable) make a server request with the details (the `$market` var) and then populate a div below with values returned from the server (dependent on what details were sent).

Here is what my code looks like

```
    <div ng-controller="MarketCtrl">

        Please select a market:

        <?php foreach ($markets as $market): ?>
            <span class="<?= strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $market)) ?>"><?= $market ?></span>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        You have selected _______ as the market.

        <div>
            <!-- Load items based on the item selected above -->
        </div>

    </div>
```

I want to do this all with AngularJS, I'm already comfortable with jQuery, but really wanna get this done using AngularJS.

What should I do for this? Should I make a new directive and then bind the above elements to the directive or something? I'm little lost at AngularJS right now, I'm going through the egghead.io videos, but haven't seen anything like this yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Please get rid of php from your view ^^

Comment: Why? I'm actually using Laravel, so it's more like view getting generated. I always think if someone can be done server side, it should be done server side... This is my default homepage view, I didn't see any reason to populate $market using JS.

Comment: Then AngularJS is not for you.  This all can be done server side...  What are you asking exactly?

Comment: @TheSharpieOne that is one really genius explanation.

Comment: @TheSharpieOne I meant at least pre populating $market variables can be done server side, they are static variables in php which the view will always load. They are not going to be changed.

Comment: In that case, @sasonic's solution will work for you.  Might I suggest `ng-init` to set the JS in the template rather than as a global called in to the controller.  You can use PHP's JSON methods to generate the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little open ended and lots of different ways to tackle. If the list of markets and corresponding detail is minimal, i would pull it all in one initial json request and have my model likes so:

```
 var markets = [{"name":"market1", "detail": {"description":"blah blah"} }]
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="MarketCtrl">
    Please select a market:
        <span ng-repeat="market in markets" ng-click="setMarket(market)" ng-class="getClass(market.name)">{{market.name}}</span>

         You have selected {{curMarket.name}}as the market.
    <div>
         {{curMarket.detail.description}}
    </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
MarketCtrl= function($scope){
    $scope.curMarket={};
    $scope.getClass = function(name){
        return name.replace(" ", "_")
    }

    $scope.setMarket(market){
         $scope.curMarket=market;
    }

}
```

If you want to call the data cause its too much:

```
var markets = [{"name":"market1", "id":1 }, {"name":"market2", "id":2}]
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="MarketCtrl">
    Please select a market:
        <span ng-repeat="market in markets" ng-click="getMarket(market)" ng-class="getClass(market.name)">{{market.name}}</span>

         You have selected {{curMarket.name}}as the market.
    <div>
         {{curMarket.detail.description}}
    </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
MarketCtrl= function($scope, $http){
    $scope.curMarket={};
    $scope.getClass = function(name){
        return name.replace(" ", "_")
    }

    $scope.getMarket(market){
         var url='';
         $http.get(url).success(function(data){
                $scope.curMarket=data;
         });
    }

}
```

Comment: Making a json sounds very logical if I have to do it this way. I'll try this out, thanks!